# How to install gdb on MacOS terminal Sierra

Tags: macos, gdb

I searched online about how to install gdb on macOS Sierra 10.12.2 but failed on the methods I could find. Then I figure out the following way which is easy and works fine on my machine. hope it may help you too:)

Comment: And how is that related to the C language??

Comment: I encountered this problem when writing C in sublime text and trying to compile and debug using terminal. Sorry for any unclearness.

Comment: If it's macOS, perhaps you simply want `lldb` instead of `gdb`?

Answer (score 49):

1. download the most recent GDB from https://www.sourceware.org/gdb/download/
2. expand the gdb-7.12.1.tar.xz file: `tar xopf gdb-7.12.1.tar.xz`
3. `cd gdb-7.12.1` in terminal to open the gdb folder
4. then follow the instructions in the README file in the gdb folder, or simply follow the following steps:
5. `./configure`, wait for the terminal
6. `make` and wait again (which can take some time)
7. `sudo make install`

Now gdb is installed at /usr/local/bin/

Comment: Do you know if this works on Mac OS High Sierra (version: 10.13.2 (17C88)) as well?

Comment: I just installed it (gdb 8.0) following this procedure as of today, it works on Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.2 (17C88).

Comment: @PhilippeSultan, amazing.  I'll try and post a comment as well to help future readers, if any.

Comment: I am getting 
Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 3244: (os/kern) failure (0x5).
 (please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))
for gdb8.1

Comment: `brew install gdb`

Comment: For the latest version "brew install gdb" is fine.  However, the steps above will allow you to install older versions which is handy.

Comment: Works for macOS Catalina 10.15 as well.

Comment: How to uninstall that if not desired anymore? ```make uninstall``` does not work

Answer (score 44):

Note that you might want to try/use LLDB (`lldb`) instead. This is now the default (don't know about 10.12, but on 10.13 it is installed, when you install the Xcode utilities). It even comes with a nice curses GUI, but otherwise a shell very similar to GDB.

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer Not always the correct answer.  CLion with openOCD does not work with LLDB, so GDB is the only option for now.  LLDB is great most of the time though.

Answer (score 15):

You can also use homebrew to get gdb in mac os:
[install-gdb-macos-sierra](https://web.archive.org/web/20190123142726/http://www.blog.howechen.com/install-gdb-macos-sierra/)

Comment: Do you know if this works on Mac OS High Sierra (version: 10.13.2 (17C88)) as well?

Comment: I didn't try it, but I think it works, the recipe of this installation is High Sierra compatible : https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/9ec9fb27a33698fc7636afce5c1c16787e9ce3f3/Formula/gdb.rb

Answer (score 6):

Surprised no one mentioned:

```
brew install gdb
```

[How to install brew?](https://brew.sh/)

Comment: m1 macos folks, Error: gdb: no bottle available!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68880134/gdb-no-bottle-available-gdb-install