# gdb: no bottle available-gdb install

Tags: macos, gdb, homebrew

I'm trying to install gdb command on my (M1) Mac OS  11.5.2, but I got brew error "gdb: no bottle available!"

I use `brew install gdb`  here's the output:

```
Error: gdb: no bottle available!
You can try to install from source with:
  brew install --build-from-source gdb
Please note building from source is unsupported. You will encounter build
failures with some formulae. If you experience any issues please create pull
requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub, Twitter or any other
official channels.
```

I try to use `brew install --build-from-source gdb` here's the output:

```
==> Downloading https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-10.2.tar.xz
Already downloaded: /Users/XX/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/3b9f42b326145a6a827e12965049f662e7fa6b9687d9263219c87418d4f8835d--gdb-10.2.tar.xz
==> ../configure --enable-targets=all --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gdb/10.2 --disable-debug --disable-dependency-tracking --with-lzma --w
==> make
==> make install-gdb maybe-install-gdbserver
Error: Empty installation
```

Here's my `brew config` output:

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 3.2.8
ORIGIN: https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/brew.git
HEAD: f026dd21c195952747395ebdda24327204f012ec
Last commit: 5 days ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/homebrew-core.git
Core tap HEAD: d91b62c128523ef6fb6dcf7b227071a8a2b561c0
Core tap last commit: 2 hours ago
Core tap branch: master
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /opt/homebrew
HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS: []
HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 8
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.3 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby
CPU: octa-core 64-bit arm_firestorm_icestorm
Clang: 12.0.5 build 1205
Git: 2.30.1 => /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/git
Curl: 7.64.1 => /usr/bin/curl
macOS: 11.5.2-arm64
CLT: 12.5.1.0.1.1623191612
Xcode: N/A
Rosetta 2: false
```

I don't know how to slove it. Please help me if you know the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You just can't build `gdb` a native arm64 package. It's not supported.

Quote from [Apple Silicon support in Homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/10152)

> We now have a majority of our formulas bottled for Apple Silicon: 70%. However, not all software is ready for ARM processors on macOS, and since we ship what upstream releases, there will be some formulas that take a long time to be fixed, have a new release… and some which will never support ARM.
>
> Our level of support is this: **Homebrew strives to ship ARM bottles for software that does support ARM**. We can't fix every software that's out there, and we won't accept feature requests like “formula Z does not support ARM can you fix it”. The most useful way you can help that software work on ARM is to open a bug report with the software developers.

That's one of the reason why Homebrew chooses `/opt/homebrew` as the homebrew prefix for M1 Mac, but not the old `/usr/local`. Users may need Apple Silicon Homebrew (installed in `/opt/homebrew`), Rosetta2 Homebrew (`/usr/local`) coexist.

So, if you really need `gdb`. Get a Rosetta 2 Homebrew installation and install it through Rosetta 2.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Lima](https://github.com/lima-vm/lima) which is something like "macOS subsystem for Linux", you can install a native arm gdb on a linux distro, but this requires recompile the code on linux.

Answer (score 0):

I can use `gdb` on Ubuntu(arm64) by using `multipass`. Maybe you can have a try~