# MacOs Big Sur: Failure to install RPM with brew

Tags: macos, homebrew, rpm

I'm trying to install rpm on mac os big sur with:

```
brew install rpm
```

but i'm getting always the same error:

```
Error: rpm: no bottle available!
```

Already tried

```
brew update
brew upgrade
brew update-reset
```

and no good.

My brew version is:

❯ brew --version
Homebrew 3.2.9-64-g6da8630

Any ideas what's going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're using an ARM Mac and the `rpm` doesn't support built as native arm64 package. You need to install a Rosetta Homebrew as well.

Check [gdb: no bottle available-gdb install](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68889531/5101148) for detail explanation.

Comment: It's not even available for Intel macOS right? I have a working 4.18.1 but can't install fresh even with "brew install rpm@4.18.1".

% brew list 'rpm' 
/usr/local/Cellar/rpm/4.18.1/bin/gendiff
/usr/local/Cellar/rpm/4.18.1/bin/rpm
/usr/local/Cellar/rpm/4.18.1/bin/rpm2archive

Comment: There is not a formula named `rpm@4.18.1`. You can't install whatever version by appending `@x.y.z` to the name.